# Counting with repetition, how to determine which one is r and which one is n

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

*** I know and understand that there are $\binom{n+r-1}{r-1}$ or $\binom{n+r-1}{n}$ ways to distribute n identical candies to r children.** But sometimes, I can't determine which one is r and which one is n.

For instance:

I can do these problems:

1. Suppose 15 identical marbles are to be selected and put into 5 numbered boxes with any number per box. How many ways this can be done?
2. Suppose 8 players are to be drafted by 4 teams, each team might win any number of these players. How many ways can these 8 players be drafted?

But I'm confused and don't know how to determine n and r in this case:

1. There are 31 flavors of ice cream. You want to buy 5 quarts. If you can pick any number of each 31 flavors, how many options do you have?

Is there a general rule to easily point out which one exactly is r and n?

Comment: The way you’ve written it above, $r$ is the number of categories, $n$ is the number of objects to place in these categories (usually these are the other way around).

Comment: @platty That was what I learned in VN and it might be wrong here. So you mean the standard way to write it in the US is: r is the number of objects and n is the number of categories?

Comment: Going along with your n 'identical' candies to r 'distinguishable' children analogy, sometimes just the designation of 'identical' vs. 'distinguishable' makes it clear. i.e. 31 flavors of ice cream are 'distinguishable' but the 5 buckets are 'identical'.

Comment: Great idea, but just to confirm: Is this always true?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'Is this always true?' but if I'm guessing what you're asking correctly then definitely not! Only when the question is equivalent to "How many ways are there to distribute n 'identical' candies to r 'distinguishable' children?" can you apply that trick. Definitely don't use in general for counting problems.

Comment: Whether you decide to write it as $\binom{n+r-1}{r-1}$ or as $\binom{r+n-1}{n-1}$ or as $\binom{a+b-1}{a-1}$ or even as $\binom{\heartsuit+\square-1}{\heartsuit-1}$ shouldn't matter.  More important than memorizing one of those is memorizing $\binom{\text{num categories + num objects}-1}{\text{num categories}-1}$ and this can be remembered by remembering how the formula was found in the first place, from stars-and-bars.  You need one fewer barrier than number of categories in order to separate the objects into groups.

Comment: As for identifying *which* items are the categories and which are the objects., answer the question for yourself of which class of item can only have one outcome at a time.  A quart presumably can only hold one flavor of icecream in it at a time, just like how a student can only be in one classroom at a time or a marble can only be in one box at a time, etc...  If neither satisfy this property then chances are the stars-and-bars technique alluded to above wouldn't work in the first place.